# svychisq with statistic="Chisq" vs. statistic="adjWald"

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, survey, survey-weights, wald-test

I'd like to run analyses using Rao-Scott Chi-squared test using svychisq to account for survey weights. It seems that statistic="Chisq" gives the Rao-Scott version, however, now that I'm looking at the documentation deeper, apparently there are other options that seems to accommodate low cell size (because statistic="Chisq" gave me a warning that the approximation may be incorrect) such as statistic="adjWald". I'm wondering whether adjWald also make adjustments on the basis of weight.

Comment: hi, yes, all the different options available in `svychisq` use the complex survey design (and with it, the survey weights)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these are all design-based tests that use the sampling weights.  The Rao-Scott tests have been shown to have better control of Type I error than the Wald and `adjWald` tests when the number of design degrees of freedom is small, but they may have lower power.